# How use infinite scrolling with angular 5+?

Tags: html, angular, infinite-scroll

I am following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll) tutorial and I am not sure if it is out of date.

I am using `@angular/core": "^5.2.0"` So I am using this version  ngx-infinite-scroll@0.8.3

I have added:

`import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';`
and imported `InfiniteScrollModule` in app.module.ts.

In `Search.component.ts` I have added `directives: [InfiniteScroll]` tp `@Component` but It does not seem to exist any more when I tabbed through the options I had in 'ngx-infinite-scroll' I could see `InfiniteScrollDirective` but did not implement it.

The only way I can get the app to compile is to get rid of `directives: [InfiniteScroll]` but the infinite scroll does not work(It is just a normal scroll).

Html:

```
<div class="search-results"
     infiniteScroll
     [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
     [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"
     (scrolled)="onScroll()">
  <div *ngFor="let name of ['a','a','b','e','r','t','t','e','b','e','r','t','ererer','a','a','b','e','r','t','t','e','b','e','r','t','ererer']">
    <div>
      {{name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-results {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

My question is what enables the infinite scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `directives: [InfiniteScroll]`. The Import inside the module is enough.

Regarding the scroll itself - do you see calls to the function you defined (`onScroll()`)?

Basically, the directive calls the `(scrolled)` function whenever a certain percentage of the element that contains the directive is shown in the viewport (80% by default).

For example, if you have a table with a height of 500px, then when 400px of it will enter the viewport (what you see on your screen), the scroll function will be called.

Comment: Ok, the On scrolled is being called and the online of code in there is logging to the console. Am I meant to use this `onScroll` function to add more data to the collection?

Comment: Exactly. And once you'll add new items, you'll increase the height of the container - which will allow the user to scroll again and, in turn, to the `onScroll` event to be thrown again (and vice versa)